# How to emit socketIO event when tab is closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mern

I am trying to make a multiplayer game using MERN stack and socketIO. I have created rooms where users can play the game and in each room, the user is connected using socketIO. I have a special "Leave" event that gets emitted when the user leaves the room to another page. This event removes the user from the room in the database. This "Leave" event gets emitted when the page gets unmounted as follows (the comments were from me trying to solve this issue):

```
      useEffect(() => {
        // window.addEveantListener('beforeunload', refresh);
        // window.addEventListener('unload', closeTab);
        //cleanup on dismount
        return () => {
          // window.removeEventListener('unload', closeTab);
          // window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', refresh);
          leaveRoom();
          if (socket) {
            socket.emit('Leave');
            socket.disconnect();
          }
        };
      }, []);
```

When the user exits the page (by clicking the leave button or navigating to a different page in the website) but doesn't close the tab, this works fine. However, when the person closes the tab directly, this doesn't work and the user remains in the room in the database. I know I could remove the user from the database room using the "disconnect" event on the server side, but that means that the user will be removed on refreshes as well, which I don't want. I have tried using window event listeners, and that solved the issue when closing tabs, but it also removed the user upon refresh. Is there any fix to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange",function() {
   console.log(":D")
});
```

for the closes, you can emit ping event every 3 seconds, and in the loop of game in the server verify if has users that has timestampt difference up than 3 seconds and disconect its. Sorry for my english,

I think socket.io also has its own ondisconnect event that you can use on the server, but I think I remember that at the time I could never make it work, it did not fire